# How do public key rings work in cryptographic applications?

Tags: public-key, signature, protocol-design

I am wondering if there are any links to articles or resources available online, or explanations that you can give, that would help me to understand the concept of a public key ring, and why I might (or might not) want to publish my public key to one or another of them.

In other words, I have a basic understanding (I hope) of how PKI works and why I'd publish my public key to a keyserver so people can find me, but I'm unclear on what these different rings mean, or what their application is.

I'm wondering what would be a good analogy for them?  Like, Google+ circles?  I am looking for a better understanding of this concept.

Comment: Hello, welcome to crypto.se :) Just a friendly note from a mod - your original title was "what are some advantages...". Normally, we see titles like that and expect a poor question (they're usually asking things that are [off topic](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/faq)) but you had a good one underneath! My advice: don't be afraid to make your question titles specific to what you're asking - that way people are much more likely to read it and answer :) Whilst I'm here, there's an edit link under the question if you want to improve on my title - feel free to do so.

Comment: Thanks :)  I like these two answers too, but don't have the reputation to upvote them yet.  Thanks guys.

Answer (score 12):

It's shockingly simple. It's a file. It has public keys in it.

The traditional PGP Key Ring is a sequential file with a sequential list of keys in it. It's not even a database.

Slightly more advanced key rings, such as those used in Key Servers actually use a database.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. It's similar to your G+ Circles or Facebook lists. Keyring is a directory of known encryption keys or Public Keys. If you are sending a message to someone that doesn't have access to this key ring, you can't send them an encrypted message.

Keyrings are more widely used in PGP (Pretty Good Privacy technique).

Answer (score 2):

Key rings are mostly used for PGP (Pretty Good Privacy) or it is also used for signing/verifying and encrypting/decrypting text.